# Hibernate Query in entire table with unique lines selects

Tags: mysql, hibernate, hql

I'm wondering how to filter Hibernate results.
For example, I have this example table:

```
--------------------------------------------
|  ID  |  STRING  |            DATE        |
--------------------------------------------
|   1  |   "ABC"  |   2014-11-07 21:45:00  |
--------------------------------------------
|   2  |   "ABC"  |   2014-11-07 22:45:00  |
--------------------------------------------
|   3  |   "DCE"  |   2014-11-07 22:48:00  |
--------------------------------------------
|   4  |   "ABC"  |   2014-11-07 23:48:00  |
--------------------------------------------
```

The result that I need is:

```
--------------------------------------------
|  ID  |  STRING  |            DATE        |
--------------------------------------------
|   3  |   "DCE"  |   2014-11-07 22:48:00  |
--------------------------------------------
|   4  |   "ABC"  |   2014-11-07 23:48:00  |
--------------------------------------------
```

All lines of table, BUT, when I have the same content in column STRING, the column with the most recent DATE is the one in result set.

In hibernate I know 
- select ALL lines;
- select the repeated lines and keep only the most recent.

But I don't know how to combine the two situations together, and I can't find it referenced anywhere.

I have a fixed length in STRING, and I use a fake primary key in my code to identify the register, but the value is inserted by user, and I have no previous knowledge of the content in the column.

Comment: Tks for the recommendations mskfisher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using a `not exists` clause:

```
select e.*
from example e
where not exists (select 1 from example e2 where e2.string = e.string and e2.date > e.date);
```

That is, select all rows where there is no other row with the same string and a larger date.

Comment: in HQL this not work, the sintax and commands are different. I can do this translation for HQL if is possible. But I don't know if I know do this, =[.

Comment: @HibernateTroubles . . . I'm pretty sure that HQL supports correlated subqueries.

Comment: Yes yes, if the database support (in my case, MySQL support) the hibernate can do this queries. I'm trying now.

Comment: IT WORKS!!! With some modifications it WORKS!!! Thank you so much!! Thank you again. You save a lot of time in my project! =]. You are the best!